# How does PHP tags parser work?

Tags: parsing, python-3.x

Im making a python webserver and how does php's parser work?

Example code:

```
Hello
<?php
echo 'hello'
?>
World
```

this should print out
Hello hello World

however im trying to make my webserver do this:

```
Hello i'm a normal text...
<?py
print('im coming from Python')
?>
Hello im also a normal text
```

How can i accomplish this type of parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this already exists: `mod_python`'s [`psp handler`](http://webpython.codepoint.net/mod_python_psp_hello_world).

However it's not a very good idea, that's why it never really took off. `mod_python` is [dead](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html) anyway.

The default for writing webapps in Python is [`wsgi`](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (for example using [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)).

Using a template engine you can pretty much do the same (embedding Python code in a template document), but with a much cleaner separation between code and templates.

Almost every Python web framework supports some templating mechanisms, you could start by looking at [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html#tutorial-templates), or [flask](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/), or [web.py](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor) ...

Comment: Im making my own webserver, is this type of parsing possible with like split?

Comment: I don't think that would get you very far, and wouldn't be very useful, but that depends on what you would like to be able to do with your syntax. I'd suggest you have a look at bottle's [templating system](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/b89562aa4b411b87e9760801bf128210c9b85ad8/bottle.py#L3129), which is a rather simple one.